# ASP.Net send and receive file question

Tags: asp.net, file-transfer

I'm completely blanking here.  I've got 2 servers that cannot talk to each other via normal network traffic (like just copying a file).  I can't get FTP setup on either server due to artificial company security constraints.

Server1 basically just has an exe on it that I have written, and it needs to send a file to Server2.

Server2 has a full blown asp.net website on it so I'm writing a .ashx page to handle receiving the file.

So...Server1 needs to make a call to server2 and send a file to it over http.  Server2 needs to accept the file and save it to disk.

Where should I start?  I know I can make server1 create a WebRequest object, and set the method to POST, and then stream the content.

But on server2, what am I supposed to write?  A generic handler?  Will my file that I send be part of the context.Request object?  How do I get it out?

I feel like I'm missing something extremely basic and just can't get my head around it.

Thanks for any pointers.

Answer (score 2):

Ok: do you have any constraints as to framework? If not, I'd highly suggest you go the WCF route and use an IIS-hosted WCF service to upload your file.

There's even a [helpful tutorial](http://kjellsj.blogspot.com/2007/02/wcf-streaming-upload-files-over-http.html) on the subject.

Answer (score 0):

Create an ASPX page on Server2 and let it host a FileUpload control.

From the exe in Server1, host a browser control and request the ASPX page, and upload the file you want via the file upload control.